# LinkedList to a String

Tags: java

How would I convert a LinkedList such as:

```
5=>2=>2=>1
```

to a String such as

```
"1225"
```

I am kind of new to java, but my guess is to pop the list and use a StringBuilder. I am just not sure how to use a StringBuilder correctly.

```
public String toString()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i <getNumberOfDigits(); i++)
    {
        sb.append(list.pop());
    }

    String toReturn = sb.toString();
    return toReturn;
}
```

EDIT:
I am not trying to sort the list, I just wanted to print it out in reverse order.

Comment: `I am just not sure how to use a StringBuilder correctly.` Is your question "How do I use a `StringBuilder`"?

Comment: So what's the problem with the use of `StringBuilder` shown in the above code?  It looks OK to me, depending on how `list` is defined.

Comment: Are you using `LinkedList` class or is it your own linked list class?

Comment: Look at the [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) documentation and in particular the `insert` method.  That may solve your problem.

Comment: @ajb it would be easier and faster to just append the data, then reverse it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Are you talking about using a string reverse?  We're not guaranteed that each list element's `toString()` is only one character, and if it isn't, a string reverse will fail.

Comment: @ajb you're right on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The StringBuilder API documentation is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). You just need to create it and then call the append method. You can then convert it using toString.

```
StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
Iterator<?> it = list.descendingIterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    string.append(it.next());
}
System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LambdaJ sorting feature like this:

```
List<Integer> list = sort(list, on(Integer.class).getItem());
```

and then you can also use the old friend **Apache common**:

```
String str = StringUtils.join(list);
```

Or using **Guava**:

```
String str = Joiner.on("").join(list);
```

Or **LambdaJ**:

```
String result = join(list, "");
```